# How to divide the foreach array into slices on php

Tags: php, pdo, foreach, slice

I have the select dropdown list where I echo the list of cities:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$cities = $pdo->query('SELECT `id`, `city` FROM `cities` ORDER BY `id` ASC');
$cities->execute();
foreach($cities as $row) {
echo '<option value="'.$row['city'].'">'.$row['city'].'</option>';
}
```

I need to divide all the cities by country with optgroup, for example now I have:

```
<select>
<option value="Edmonton">Edmonton</option>
<option value="Ottawa">Ottawa</option>
<option value="Winnipeg">Winnipeg</option>
<option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
<option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
<option value="New York">New York</option>
</select>
```

and I need to get:

```
<optgroup label="Canada">
<option value="Edmonton">Edmonton</option>
<option value="Ottawa">Ottawa</option>
<option value="Winnipeg">Winnipeg</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="USA">
<option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
<option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
<option value="New York">New York</option>
</optgroup>
```

The list and ID won't be changed, I demonstrated example only so it's enough to divide by ID

Comment: I dont think `array_slice()` is the way to go. There can be 5 cities in one land or only 1, so he cant know when to slice. He needs another field in the database which defines in which land the city is.

Comment: set qry as group by country ...

Comment: No, another field in the DB is unnecessary, the list won't be changed, so it's enough to divide it by ID: from id=1 to id=3 and so on..

Comment: And what do you do when there are 4 new cities added which are all located in the USA? Using the ID to set values correctly in such a case is a terrible practice. You HAVE TO add a new field for each country.

Comment: The list and ID won't be changed, I demonstrated example only :)

Comment: foreach ($cities as $key=>$row){if(key%3==2){echo '<optgroup label="Country">';} echo '<option value="'.$row['city'].'">'.$row['city'].'</option>';}

Comment: @Andreea, it's near but nothing changed - I still get all the same

Comment: @jumlancer If you really do it that way, its damn dirty and almost impossible to improve. Software should always be programmed in a way where you can extend it as easy as possible. But if you want to use `array_slice()`, go on.

Comment: @Y U NO WORK, you are probably right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to modify your db, to have country column.
Then, follow this code.

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$cities = $pdo->query('SELECT `id`, `city`, `country` FROM `cities` ORDER BY `id` ASC');
$cities->execute();
$data = array();
foreach($cities as $row) {
$data[$row['country']][] = $row['city'];
}
foreach($data as $country){
echo "<optgroup label='{$country}'>";
foreach($country as $city){
echo "<option value='{$city}'>{$city}</option>";
}
echo "</optgroup>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get the optgroups where I need but all with the label "Array". What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand o.k, but if you want to group the cities by their country you need to get from database the contry too. Hope this helps